# Overlapping of dropdown menu with another item

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

**EDIT**

My jsfiddle entry is [here : http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/3/)

All the codes(only those required) below are there, I updated upon the request of @Jasper... tho some parts may be missing as i had to trim down the huge code

**PS**: While clicking for the drop down menu in jsfiddle, you cannot see the red down arrow as its an image in the local system, but you can just click on where the arrow is supposed to be to see the effect.

**ORIGINAL POST**

[image]
[image]

The above images explains my problem... whats the problem with my drop down menu? Why is it overlapping with my `entry` div class below.... Can anyone suggest a remedy for it? ... I am using the [codes from here](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html) to develop this... also I dono where the extra space is coming from

My markup HTML (with jquery for the dropdown):

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">



        <li><a href="#">Live-Radio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Songs</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)

        $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

            $(this).parent().hover(function() {
            }, function(){
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
            });

            //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
            }).hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
            }, function(){  //On Hover Out
                $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
        });

    });

    </script>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#menu{
    float:left;
    height:71px;
    padding-top:35px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 400px;
}

ul.topnav {    
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    z-index:50;
}
ul.topnav li {

    height:100px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}
ul.topnav li a{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #222;
    display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul.topnav li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/down.png) no-repeat center top;
}
ul.topnav li span.subhover {cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/
ul.topnav li ul.subnav {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0; top: 35px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
ul.topnav li ul.subnav li{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    width: 170px;
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    background: #333 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/
    background: #222 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
}



.entry{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background:#eee url(images/entrybg.png) repeat-x;
    color:#333;
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

And the below `<div class="entry"> ... </div>` creates the box you see with the title `What's happening at Bedupako.Com`

Comment: PS: I tried to give z-index of 100 to #menu ID but it didnt work :(

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle of your code? This is a lot to take-in in this format: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Jasper I have updated and given a link to JSFiddle entry... please have a look.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the JavaScript/jQuery from your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas ... I updated the codes now.... updated the post here too... the JS was embedded in HTML, now i just put the required one separate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, your menu is overlapping your content area because it does not understand who goes first in the stream, since your submenu is absolutely positioned. To fix this, just declare a position to your `#menu` container and add a `z-index` of something like `9999` to position it above everything else.

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

As for your second issue, the submenu items are inheriting the height of your main menu items, which is 100 pixels, simply declare a `height:auto` to your submenu `li` items to fix this.

```
ul.topnav li ul.subnav li {
    height: auto;
}
```

EDIT::

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/ehNrE/6/

Comment: THANKS :D I am a little weak in front-end, didnt notice these ... thanks again!... accepted yours as you posted first!

Comment: Hi, 1 more doubt, No matter what z-index i give, If there is a FLASH embedded in the page, that always comes top, How to prevent that?

Comment: You have to define a `wmode="transparent"` attribute to your `<object>` or `<embed>` tag to position it behind your html content.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your menu is appearing behind your content is because `z-index` in `ul.topnav` will not work with `static` positioning. To fix this you can simply apply `relative` positioning:

```
ul.topnav {
    position: relative;    /* add this */   
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    z-index:50;
}
```

The reason there is extra spacing in the sub-nav is because `li` elements in `.subnav` are inheriting `height: 100px` from the CSS styling in `ul.topnav li`. To get around this you should remove `height: 100px` from `ul.topnav li` and add it to `#menu` instead:

```
#menu{
    height:100px;    /* add this */
    float:left;
    height:71px;
    padding-top:35px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 400px;
}

ul.topnav li {
    /* height:100px;   remove this */
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}
```

**JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/5/**

Comment: THANKS :D I am a little weak in front-end, didnt notice these ... thanks again!...

Comment: No problem, glad we could help :)